# backbonejs - Why is this backbonejs model content doesn't change?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

i've just started to learn backbonejs. This is some of my demo lines of code:

```
        var i = 0;
        Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
            default: {
                name : "noName",
                HP: 100,
                MP: 100
            },
            initialize: function(){
                i++;
                this.name = "Player "+i.toString();
                alert(this.name+" created !");
                this.on("change:name", function(model){
                    var name = model.get("name");
                    alert("Change "+this.name+ " to "+name);
                });

            }
        });

        var p1 = new Player({HP: 200});
        var p2 = new Player({MP: 200});
        p1.set({name: "A"});
        p2.set({name:"B"});
        p1.set({name: "A2"});
```

Now what confused me is that why when i run this code on browser, it appears:

```
Player 1 created !
Player 2 created !
Change Player 1 to A
Change Player 2 to B
Change Player 1 to A2
```

(why not **Change A to A2 ?**, cause i've already change Player 1 to A before ?)

Comment: you have an error - not default: {} bu defaults: {}

Comment: i changed default to defaults but that doesn't change the output i'm talking about @@

Comment: because you set this.name = "Player "+i.toString(); - it saved in object root, p2.set({name:"B"}); - update data in attribute hash.

Comment: then could you tell me how to fix that, i want the result is "Change A to A2" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First an important thing to understand is that:

```
this.name = "Player "+i;
```

is not like doing:

```
this.set("name", "Player" + i);
```

`this.name` is just adding field name in the javascrip object while `this.set("name", ...)` is changing the Backbone model property (as intended)

Here is my proposal for you code:

```
defaults: {
  name : "noName",
  HP: 100,
  MP: 100
},
initialize: function(){
  i++;
  this.on("change:name", function(model){
    alert("Change "+model.previous("name")+ " to "+ model.get("name"));
  });
  this.set('name', "Player "+ i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **previous**  to get value of model attribute you have changed + get and set attribute value correctly. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkRcF/)

```
var i = 0;
Player = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        name : "noName",
        HP: 100,
        MP: 100
    },

    initialize: function(){
        i++;
        this.set('name', "Player "+i.toString());
        alert(this.get('name')+" created !");
        this.on("change:name", function(model){
            var prevName = model.previous("name");
                name = model.get("name");
            alert("Change "+prevName+ " to "+name);
        });
    }
});


var p1 = new Player({HP: 200}),
    p2 = new Player({MP: 200});

p1.set({name: "A"});
p2.set({name:"B"});
p1.set({name: "A2"});
```